# Yii2 Call to a member function someFunction() on Integer and a non-object

Tags: php, yii2

I wanna show usernames in timeline index. It show error

> Call to a member function getStatusesLabel() on integer

if use this code :

```
'status' =>$model->data['status']->getStatusesLabel(),
```

and

```
'author' => $model->data['author']->getAuthor(),
```

and another error

> Trying to get property of non-object

if use this code :

```
'author' => ArrayHelper::map($model->data['author']->getAuthor, 'id','username'),
```

My Model

```
namespace common\models;
.....  
class Article extends ActiveRecord
{
   .....
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'author_id']);
    }


    public function getUpdater()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'updater_id']);
    }


    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ArticleCategory::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
    }

    public function getArticleAttachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticleAttachment::className(), ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public static function statuses()
    {
        return [
            self::STATUS_PUBLISHED => Yii::t('common', 'Published'),
            self::STATUS_DRAFT => Yii::t('common', 'Draft'),
        ];
    }

    public function afterCreate()
    {
      $this->refresh();
      // use common\commands\AddToTimelineCommand;
          Yii::$app->commandBus->handle(new AddToTimelineCommand([
            'category' => 'articles',
            'event' => '_item',
            'data' => [
              'title' => $this->title,
              'published_at' => $this->published_at,
              'created_at' => $this->created_at,
              'slug' => $this->slug,
              'author' => $this->author_id,
              'category' => $this->category,
              'status' => $this->status,
            ]
          ]));
    }


    public function afterUpdate()
    {
      $this->refresh();
      // use common\commands\AddToTimelineCommand;
          Yii::$app->commandBus->handle(new AddToTimelineCommand([
            'category' => 'articles',
            'event' => '_itemU',
            'data' => [
              'title' => $this->title,
              'published_at' => $this->published_at,
              'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
              'slug' => $this->slug,
              'author' => $this->author_id,
              'category' => $this->category,
              'status' => $this->status,
            ]
          ]));
    }
}
```

my controller article:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Article();
    $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

    try{
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $model->afterCreate();
        $transaction->commit();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'categories' => ArticleCategory::find()->active()->all(),
        ]);
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
              $transaction->rollBack();
            }
}
```

controller timeline

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new TimelineEventSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->sort = [
            'defaultOrder'=>['created_at'=>SORT_DESC]
        ];

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
```

command timeline :

```
class AddToTimelineCommand extends Object implements SelfHandlingCommand
{
    public $category;
    public $event;
    public $data;
    public function handle($command)
    {
        $model = new TimelineEvent();
        $model->application = Yii::$app->id;
        $model->category = $command->category;
        $model->event = $command->event;
        $model->data = json_encode($command->data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        return $model->save(false);
    }
}
```

index timeline:

```
<ul class="timeline">
                <?php foreach($dataProvider->getModels() as $model): ?>
                    <?php if(!isset($date) || $date != Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at)): ?>
                        <!-- timeline time label -->
                        <li class="time-label">
                            <span class="bg-blue">
                                <?php echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at) ?>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                        <?php $date = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php
                            try {
                                $viewFile = sprintf('%s/%s', $model->category, $model->event);
                                echo $this->render($viewFile, ['model' => $model]);
                            } catch (\yii\base\InvalidParamException $e) {
                                echo $this->render('_item', ['model' => $model]);
                            }
                        ?>
                    </li>
```

view _item for index:

```
<div class="timeline-body">
        <?php echo Yii::t('backend', 'Updated post <b>({title})</b>, published date : {published_at} ', [
            'title' => Html::a($model->data['title'],
            Url::to(Yii::$app->urlManager->hostInfo.'/article'.'/')  .$model->data['slug'],
            ['target' => '_blank']),
            //'author' => ArrayHelper::map($model->data['author']->getAuthor, 'id','username'),
            //'author' => $model->data['author']->getAuthor(),
            'author' => $model->data['author'],
            'category' => $model->data['category'],
            //'status' =>$model->data['status']->getStatusesLabel(),
            'published_at' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->data['published_at']),
            'updated_at' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->data['updated_at'])
        ])//.Html::a($model->data['title'], ["/article/$model->data['title']"]) ?>
    </div>
```

what is wrong with the above code?
i was use in GridView / detailview, there is no errors
how do I fix it?

Comment: Looking at your code is not clear  in which file you use  'status' =>$model->data['status']->getStatusesLabel(),   you use this code in gridView ? ..please show the related code too

Comment: i forget to add controllers. in my gridview i use this code : [
                'attribute'=>'author_id',
                'value'=>function ($model) {
                    return $model->author->username;
                }
            ],

Answer (score 0):

In a simple view (not based on gridview or detailView widget)  that you render using eg:

```
  return $this->render('your_view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

you can use directly the model and the attribute (or the depending function) eg:

 'author' => $model->author
```

If you instead use a

```
  return $this->render('your_view', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

you can refer to the model instance

```
  'author' => $dataProvider->models[i]['author']
```

where  i is the index for the specific instance

Comment: i still can't show attribute from another table, but thank you for your answer